# Site breaks in IE6 on "Unexpected call to method or property access" error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iepngfix

http://farmball.com/boston

The line that 'causes' the error:

```
IEPNGFix.process(element, 0);
```

Full code: http://pastie.org/648568

Note: I tried searching the phrase and IEPNGFix in Google, no luck. Also tried the MIRC Javascript chatroom before coming here.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the hook function to:

```
IEPNGFix.hook = function(elm) {
    if (IEPNGFix.hook.enabled) {
        IEPNGFix.process(elm, 0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you define `element` as anything.  Try passing in a valid element value to the `IEPNGFix.process` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the hook function this way works for me:

```
IEPNGFix.hook = function(evt) {
    if (IEPNGFix.hook.enabled) {
        IEPNGFix.process(evt.srcElement, 0);
    }
};
```

Reference is here:
http://www.twinhelix.com/cgi-bin/forum.pl/iepngfix/531